# R - Transpose columns and rows with conditions

Tags: r

I am working with the dataframe 'by_class_survival' and I am trying to convert in other format, changing the rows and columns plus including conditions, I have already solved in a very rustic way, so but I am wondering if there is a better way to transpose columns and rows, plus adding conditions at the moment to create the transposition.

```
library(dplyr)

titanic_tbl <- dplyr::tbl_df(Titanic)
titanic_tbl <- titanic_tbl %>%
mutate_at(vars(Class:Survived), funs(factor))
by_class_survival <- titanic_tbl %>%
group_by(Class, Survived) %>%
summarize(Count = sum(n))
```

Original dataframe

```
# Class Survived Count
# 1 1st   No         122
# 2 1st   Yes        203
# 3 2nd   No         167
# 4 2nd   Yes        118
# 5 3rd   No         528
# 6 3rd   Yes        178
# 7 Crew  No         673
# 8 Crew  Yes        212
```

Creating a new dataframe based on the values from by_class_survival

```
first <- c(122,203)
second <- c(167, 118)
third <- c(528,178)
crew <- c(673,212)

titanic.df = data.frame(first,second,third,crew)

library(data.table)
t_titanic.df <- transpose(titanic.df)
rownames(t_titanic.df) <- colnames(titanic.df)
colnames(t_titanic.df) <- c("No survivor", "Survivor")
```

Expected result

```
##        No survivor Survivor
## first          122      203
## second         167      118
## third          528      178
## crew           673      212
```

There is a better way to reach the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in one step with `reshape2::dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

titanic_tbl %>%
 dcast(Class ~ Survived, value.var = "n", sum)

  Class  No Yes
1   1st 122 203
2   2nd 167 118
3   3rd 528 178
4  Crew 673 212
```

or you can use `tidyr::spread` on the summarised data frame:

```
library(tidyr)
titanic_tbl %>%
  group_by(Class, Survived) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(n)) %>%
  spread(Survived, sum)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Class [4]
  Class    No   Yes
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 1st     122   203
2 2nd     167   118
3 3rd     528   178
4 Crew    673   212
```

Comment: The resolution using `tidyr::spread` works perfect! The first one with `dplyr` is almost perfect because it is showing   `#Survived 1st 2nd 3rd Crew
#1       No 122 167 528  673
#2      Yes 203 118 178  212`. Thank you for the second one!